# "Unstaged changes after reset" after every reset

Tags: git

I am learning how to use Git. I get the message "Unstaged changes after reset:
M index.html "after each reset, I have not made any changes to the file. I have used git checkout and it allowed me to continue, but it happens again when doing another reset. I still don't know very well what the checkout function is since I am starting and this does not allow me to advance quietly, how can I make it stop appearing as modified if I have not done anything?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS and Git version.

You can check the difference with `git diff`.

But try first:

```sh
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git clone https://remote/repo/url anotherFolder
```

Check in that new local clone if the issue persists: an automatic modification can be cause by eol (end of line) transformation.

The [OP Rodrigo Vergara Gonzalez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16575783/rodrigo-vergara-gonzalez) confirms this works, after a `git reset --hard`.
(Warning: this would reset any file currently being modified: use with caution)

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Using the gitclone command I see that the folder is created but it disappears immediately with the error "Cloning into 'anotherFolder' ...
fatal: unable to access 'https: // remote / repo / url /': Could not resolve
host: remote "

Comment: @RodrigoVergaraGonzalez Sure, this is expected: you are supposed to *replace* "remote/repo/url by the actual remote repository URL. (like `https://github.com/<me>/<myRepo>`)

Comment: Sorry, the anxiety haha. I followed the instructions, did a few commits and when I use "git reset" the problem persists :(

Comment: @RodrigoVergaraGonzalez OK. What is your OS, OS version and Git version?

Comment: Windows 10 Home, Version 21H1. Git Version 2.32.0.windows.2
I tried "git reset --hard" and it works perfect. I will use it as a tool for now.

Comment: @RodrigoVergaraGonzalez Perfect. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.